# How to remove two of the same elements in two different ArrayLists?

Tags: java

Just started to learn Java and have a question on how I can remove the common elements from two different Arraylists?

My thought process went with:

```
 for(int i =0; i<playerOneInputArray.size(); i++) {
       if(playerOneInputArray.contains(playerTwoInputArray.get(i))){
           playerOneInputArray.remove(playerTwoInputArray.get(i));

       }
   }
```

however, when I check the out put i get:

```
Player One! Choose your word!
hello
Player Two! Choose your word!
hellow
[h, e, l, l, o]
[h, e, l, l, o, w]
[e, l]
```

which I expected to only get a [w] in my new playerOneInputArray

what's going on?? :C

Comment: `List#removeAll()` should work perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are *concurrently modifying* a data structure. Specifically, you are editing an ArrayList that you are iterating over.

Consider the simplified problem of removing any even numbers from an arrayList. You may consider using this approach:

```
public void removeEvens(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        if(arr.get(i) % 2 == 0) arr.remove(i);
    }
}
```

But there is an issue with this approach. Consider the sample input:

```
1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8
```

When we hit `i = 2`, we correctly remove `4`. However, at the next iteration (`i = 3`), the arrayList now looks like:

```
1, 3, 6, 7, 8
```

So we are checking `7`, not `6`. By removing an element *and* moving `i` forward, we effectively skipped checking an element.

Your code is doing a similar operation, and suffers from a similar problem. You can both simplify your code and correct the issue by using built-in functions, such as `removeAll`:

```
playerOneInputArray.removeAll(playerTwoInputArray);
```

This will remove the duplicates from `playerOneInputArray`, but if you want to do this to `playerTwoInputArray` you'll have to change it a little bit, as once you've removed the duplicates from the first arrayList you can't remember which duplicates you removed. If that is the case, consider:

```
ArrayList<Character> duplicates = new ArrayList<Character>(playerOneInputArray);
duplicates.retainAll(playerTwoInputArray);
playerOneInputArray.removeAll(duplicates);
playerTwoInputArray.removeAll(duplicates);
```

Comment: Does remove() not affect the size of the arraylist?

Comment: It does, but that doesn't prevent the concurrent modification problem. In the example given we're nowhere near the end of the list, yet we had a problem anyways.

Comment: Oh My Goodness Thank you so much for that example! I literally just "AHH-ed" incrediliy loud at my local library haha. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you modify your `playerOneInputArray` in loop. Your code doesnt work as you expect because when you do `remove()`, then `playerOneInputArray.size()` changes. So, i recommend to use `removeAll(playerTwoInputArray)` instead of remove in loop.

Answer (score 0):

An observation about your code:

You will encounter index out of bounds exception when the first array is longer than the second.

Also you will not check all elements between the arrays when the two arrays have different sizes because you are only using the size of the first array for the loop. Doing that creates the potential for the first issue I mentioned as well.

You need to handle these cases in some way as opposed to skipping some data or having an error.